# Remove disabled attribute from a form field when toggle a button

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to remove the disabled attribute when I toggle a button (to on) and viceversa.

At this time I have only created a click event to remove the disabled attr.

The HTML is :
Input:

```
 <input id="wb_owner_field" type="text" disabled value="" placeholder="" class="form-control">
```

And the on/off toggle when is off it has the class : `switch-off` and when its on it has class `switch-on`

```
<div id="wb_owner_toggle" class="switch-off switch-animate" style="">
  <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="switch">
  <span class="switch-left"></span><label>&nbsp;</label>
  <span class="switch-right"></span>
</div>
```

Code used until now.

```
$("#wb_owner_toggle").click(function(){
      $('#wb_owner_field').prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Basically I need to fir-up when the toggle div class is changed and to remove or add the disabled attr on the field based on the class.

Comment: Is there any good reason you're showing fragmented code parts, and not a minimal, complete verifiable example?

Comment: Im not fully understanding the question. Do you want to remove disabled only if it has a certain class?

Comment: @AmmarCSE yes that`s correct. When the class of the toggle div is switch-off the form needs to have disabled attr. and when the toggle div has switch-on the form needs to have disabled attr removed.

Comment: If you have a checkbox I actually think you also should consider to test if it is checked instead of test for a specific class. You can do this with `$('#the-checkbox-element').is(':checked')`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**hasClass()**](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

```
$("#wb_owner_toggle").click(function(){
      if($(this).hasClass('switch-off')){
            $('#wb_owner_field').prop("disabled", false);
      }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
$("#wb_owner_toggle").click(function(){
      var owner_el = $('#wb_owner_field');
      owner_el.attr('disabled', !owner_el.is(':disabled'));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is that `disabled` attribute is **boolean attribute**.

> The presence of a boolean attribute on an element represents the true
>   value, and the absence of the attribute represents the false value.
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes

Please, read carefully. The false value – is the absence of that attribute.

`disabled="false"` is totally incorrect.

So, the right way to remove it by jQuery is:

`element.removeAttr('disabled');`

If this algorithm confirms your case, the code will be:

```
$("#wb_owner_toggle").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('switch-off')) {
    $('#wb_owner_field').removeAttr('disabled');
  }
  else {
    $('#wb_owner_field').attr('disabled');
  }
});
```